# Plot and Scatter legend on subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

My code looks like this:

```
pos = 0
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,3,4]
y2 = [3,5,3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
for pos in [0,1]:
    h1 = axs[pos].scatter(x,y,c='black',label='scttr')
    h2 = axs[pos].plot(x,y2,c='red',label='line')
    axs[pos].legend([h1, h2])
plt.show()
```

which produces the right legend without text (it shows the object name in the handle). If I try to produce some text for the labels:

```
pos = 0
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,3,4]
y2 = [3,5,3]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
for pos in [0,1]:
    h1 = axs[pos].scatter(x,y,c='black',label='scttr')
    h2 = axs[pos].plot(x,y2,c='red',label='line')
    axs[pos].legend([h1, h2],['smtng', 'smtng2')
plt.show()
```

the code crashes with the following:

> A proxy artist may be used instead. See:
>   http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist
>   "#using-proxy-artist".format(orig_handle))

I did not really understand what [proxy artists](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#using-proxy-artist) are and why I would need one for such a basic thing.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you can't pass the `Line` objects directly to the `legend` call. What you can do, instead, is create some different objects ([known as proxy artists](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html#creating-artists-specifically-for-adding-to-the-legend-aka-proxy-artists)) to fill the gap, so to speak.

Below are two proxy objects, `scatter_proxy` and `line_proxy`, for the scatter plot and line plot, respectively. You create both using [`matplotlib.lines.Line2D`](http://matplotlib.org/api/lines_api.html#matplotlib.lines.Line2D) but the one for the scatter plot has a white line (so isn't effectively seen) and has markers added to it. I realise making the line color white is a bit hacky, but it was the best way I could find.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as mlines

pos = 0
x = [1,2,3]
y = [2,3,4]
y2 = [3,5,3]

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)

scatter_color = 'black'
line_color='red'

for pos in [0,1]:
    h1 = axs[pos].scatter(x, y, c=scatter_color, label='scttr')
    h2 = axs[pos].plot(x, y2, c=line_color, label='line')

    scatter_proxy = mlines.Line2D([], [], color='white', marker='o', markerfacecolor=scatter_color)
    line_proxy = mlines.Line2D([], [], color=line_color)

    axs[pos].legend([scatter_proxy, line_proxy],['smtng', 'smtng2'])

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: nice hack. I am using seaborn, would you know what is the default background color?

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis I've managed to get the axes color using `bkgd_color = plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor']` to use to make the line "invisible" but I'm having the issue that the markers aren't appearing anyway. Will play around a bit and see what I can manage. If you fix it yourself, let me know :P

Comment: Simply set the line color to `'none'`. Then it is actually invisible independent of the background color

Comment: That fixes the line color nicely, but doesn't change the fact that (with seaborn) the markers aren't visible.

Comment: @hitzg, @Ffisegydd: setting the line color to `'none'` worked for me and the markers remain visible. I did not manage to replicate @Ffisegydd issue. tnx to the both of you.

Comment: @NoIdeaHowToFixThis have you seen my answer? You can do this without proxy artists (see the last part of my answer)

Answer (score 1):

At least in your simple example, it is way simpler if you don't pass any handles to  `legend`:

```
...
axs[pos].legend()
...
```

Result:

[image]

You can overwrite the labels like this:

```
...
axs[pos].legend(['smtng', 'smtng2'])
...
```

Result: 
[image]

If you want to use the handles, you can. However, you have to consider that `plot` returns a list of Line objects. Thus you have to pass it to `legend` like this:

```
...
axs[pos].legend([h1, h2[0]],['smtng', 'smtng2'])
...
```

You only need to use proxy artists if you want to add something to the legend which does not exist in you plot or if you want (for some reason) make it look different in the legend than in the plot.